# Fastreport 5 summaryReport at bottom of the page

Tags: delphi, fastreport

For work I need to convort old fastreport stuf to fastreport 5. In the old version of Fastreport there was an option for reportsummary to put it at the bottom of the page. It isn't here in fastreport 5. I googled alot and I am not the only one with this problem. I tried using delphi code that i found on the internet but that didn't work for me. Can anyone help me? I am using delphi version 5.0.0

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following script in before print event on report summary band :

```
procedure ReportSummary1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  Engine.CurY := Engine.CurY + Engine.FreeSpace - ReportSummary1.Height-1;      
end;
```

This works in fast report 4.0.